# On Click, Can I open a Excel File using php which is already saved?

Tags: download, phpexcel

I created a form in php. And All That details placed in Excel Sheet using php program.
And After that I done some changes in that  Excel Sheet.Now,I want to open that  Excel Sheet using On click Event in php.

Thank You,

Regards
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a real link (javascript can't help you for this)

```
<a href="my_url" target="_blank">Download Excel</a>
```

the url should call a php file just returning the already created Excel